# PySpark - Split Array Column into smaller chunks

Tags: pyspark

Let's say i have a dataset with a Column

```
 # Output
 #+-----------------+
 #|         arrayCol|
 #+-----------------+
 #| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |
 #+-----------------+
```

I want to know if it is possible to split this column into smaller chunks of max_size without using UDF.

The result desired is as following with a max_size = 2 :

```
 # Output
 #+-----------------------+
 #|               arrayCol|
 #+-----------------------+
 #| [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]] |
 #+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of using `transform` and `filter` is using if and using mod to decide the splits and using `slice` (slices an array)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
n = 2
df.withColumn("NewCol",F.expr(f""" 
               filter(
         transform(arrayCol,(x,i)-> if (i%{n}=0 ,slice(arrayCol,i+1,{n}), null)),x->
               x is not null)                               
""")).show(truncate=False)


+---------------+---------------------+
|arrayCol       |NewCol               |
+---------------+---------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]|
+---------------+---------------------+
```